# Content negotiation in Noir

Tags: clojure, noir

What is the prefered way to do content negotiation in the [Noir](http://webnoir.org/) framework?

I am aware of this [clj-conneg](https://github.com/rnewman/clj-conneg), but I'd like to know if similar functionality is already included in Noir.

Answer (score 2):

Because Noir is built upon Ring, middleware such as [ring-middleware-format](https://github.com/ngrunwald/ring-middleware-format) is probably the way to go.